# Active moderators can join new election

Tags: bug, election

I'm a moderator on Stack Overflow на Русском (Stack Overflow in Russian). Currently there is [new election](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election). And suddenly I can join it.

> [image]

I think, an active moderator shouldn't be able to join election.

Comment: You get two diamonds if you win ...

Comment: @rene nice addition to my collection :D

Comment: Not sure this is a bug: pro-tem moderators would have to nominate in an election if they want to be re-elected when the site 'graduates' or loses it's beta label. May just be easier to not block any moderators from running ;-)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Hmm well, what if a (especially a newer) moderator wants to have a confirmation from the sites community? On the other hand I agree, they cannot win or loose their mod privilege from that election.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elected moderators can nominate themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101370/282094), along with that exact dupe (and it's dupe) there are other considerations (why they should be on the ballot):  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136944/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221966/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301344/282094